# Difference between the openness of $f$ if we restrict the codomain to be $[-1,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the map $f(x) = \sin(x)$. Is there a difference between the openness of $f$ if we restrict the codomain to be $[-1,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

I've been trying to figure out if the codomain restriction has any affect on the openess of the map $f$ and I don't know how to think about this.

I think that for any $(a,b)$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology we have that $f(a,b) = (\sin(a), \sin(b))$ which is open so I would assume that $f$ is open no matter if the domain is $\Bbb R$ or $[-1,1]$?

Comment: What you claim is not quite right.  For example, with $(a,b)=(0,\pi)$ its image is not $f(a,b)=(0,0) = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 4):

The issue in your argument is that since $\sin$ is not strictly increasing, it is not true in general that the image $\sin((a, b))$ is $(\sin a, \sin b)$.

In particular, if there is a "crest" of the sine wave (ie a point $x$ of the form $(k + 1/2)\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbf{Z}$ where $\sin x$ is either $-1$ or $1$) between $a$ and $b$, then the point $-1$ or $1$ but no more extreme points are included in the image.

That is, possible images of the interval $(a, b)$ are of the form

1. $(\sin a, \sin b)$ or $(\sin b, \sin a)$
2. $(\sin a, 1]$ or $(\sin b, 1]$
3. $[-1, \sin b)$ or $[-1, \sin a)$
4. $[-1, 1]$

While only sets in the case (1.) are open in $\mathbf{R}$, they are all open in $[-1, 1]$.
That is, $\sin$ is open when its codomain is $[-1, 1]$ but not $\mathbf{R}$.